# HardHat does not build artifacts when i compile the contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, json-rpc, hardhat

I compile the contract but the json file and the debug file does not appear in the artifacts.i get this from the compiler: "Compiled 1 Solidity file successfully", i have the default hardhat config.js with solidity:0.8.4".
npm version:'6.14.16'.[image] [image]

[image: i looked in the directory and does not appear]

Comment: Make sure you save the .sol file, VS Code doesn't auto save by default. View the file using Notepad to make sure it has code. Otherwise, post hardhat config and the sol file here.

Comment: Pro tip: take a look at my [hardhat-template](https://github.com/paulrberg/hardhat-template).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox` installed properly, it wil help with the generation of the missing files, deployment of your contract as well.

Check out docs for proper installation here: https://openbase.com/js/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox